# Transfer file from Windows 10 to Linux through azure cli?

Tags: linux, ssh, windows, file-transfer

I have a Windows 10 virtual machine and I would like to transfer a file to a linux machine which is on Azure.

I installed the **AADSSHLogin** extension on the linux machine via the Azure portal. Through Azure CLI installed on Windows 10, I connected to the linux machine in this way to check the ssh connection:

```
az login
az ssh vm --ip 10.11.11.11
```

It was successful, I tried via powershell on Windows 10 to transfer the file on Linux:

```
scp file.sh myuser@10.11.11.11:/opt/Linux/
```

And it asks me for the password but it doesn't work. I have the impression that I have to use an azure cli command to transfer the file since I have connected with **az login**, I have searched and there is **azcopy** but it does not seem the correct one.

I noticed that if I do on powershell:

```
ssh myuser@dominio.org@10.11.11.11
```

it tells me: **Permission denied (publickey)**

But if I do:

```
az ssh vm --ip 10.11.11.11
```

I can get in!

What should I do? What am I missing?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/copy-files-to-linux-vm-using-scp

Comment: @aviro why's that relevant? It covers use of the standard `scp` command. It doesn't seem to address the question asked here

Comment: Thanks @aviro and @roaima! Maybe my user has some problems, I wrote the command better since my user is myuser@dominio.org and it tells me this: **myuser@dominio.org@10.11.11.11: Permission denied (publickey)**. 
do I have to copy the public key I have on windows on linux, for example .ssh/authorized_keys?

Answer (score 5):

The Azure CLI doesn't support file transfers directly; there's no `az scp` or `az ssh scp` command. But it does support OpenSSH-based applications indirectly.

First, run this command:

```
az ssh config --ip * --file ./azure-sshconfig --keys-destination-folder ./azure-keys
```

The [`az ssh config` command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ssh?view=azure-cli-latest&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#az-ssh-config) will create a local `azure-sshconfig` file along with an `azure-keys` folder containing an OpenSSH-style configuration and keys that are capable of accessing the Azure VM. Note that the keys have a limited lifetime; as of this writing, they will expire after an hour, and that doesn't seem to be configurable.

Once you have your config and keys, you can use other OpenSSH utilities such as `scp` and `sftp`, both of which take a `-F ./azure-sshconfig` argument to instruct them to use your temporary keys:

```
scp -F ./azure-sshconfig <local file> <vm name>:~/temp
```

It may also be possible to get `rsync` (e.g., in WSL) working by passing `--rsh 'ssh -F ./azure-sshconfig'` - in this case, `rsync` doesn't take an `-F sshconfig` argument directly but you can override its `ssh` completely. I haven't tried this but it should work.

Comment: Great info! I had to do the `az ssh` step referencing a resource group (-g) + VM Name (-n) combination. In that case, replace <vm name> here with <resource group-vm name>. For example, `az ssh -g MyResourceGroup -n MyVirtualMachine` would mean I use `scp -F ./azure-sshconfig <local file> MyResourceGroup-MyVirtualMachine:~/temp`